man drives to a secret island with motor boat, gets shot and falls from cliff into sea
I know thats a very vague description but that is the most detailed part I can remember. 
Let's see what else I can remember about the movie. 

I think the movie starts of in an exotic country like africa or brazil, but then I think the location is US
Time period was modern time so right now or the 2000's +
I think it has a Sequel
The actor is a very handsome but I think not too famous actor (he is male)
I think he is the son of a very rich father or family and at the end I can remember he even works at that company in a big skyscraper
I can vaguely remember how the movie starts => I think he sleeps with a woman in a very exotic land in a very sordid hotel
The scene I mentioned in the title is following: I think somehow the actor got the information that there is a secret or more hidden villa on an island. He headed over to this island with a motor boat. He found it and then I think helicopters joined in and shot him while he is standing on a cliff, he  then fell into the sea. But he is still alive and I think from then on he wants to take revenge
I think the movie is about revenge
The movie is at least 5 - 10 years old (not sure about that). 
I think but that's really just a intuition, the movie name is called like the guy's family name. But not sure about that. 


Oh got after another excessive google session I could finally find the movie title. 
Largo Winch - 2008



Wikipedia extract

However, Largo has traveled to a secret island, containing a monastery, where Nerio has a secret safe in which he holds his stocks. After unlocking the safe, he is cornered by Marcus. After taking his shares, Marcus tries to kill him, but Largo escapes and jumps into the sea, although he is shot and badly injured. 

